# Python watchdog for files from two different directories

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I am trying to listen to filesystem changes using the watchdog module of Python. I want to monitor the files from two different directories. For a single file watch, I used `PatternMatchingEventHandler` from `watchdog.events`. I want to use the same for multiple directories.

**code:**

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class EventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        super(EventHandler, self).on_modified(event)
        print event

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir_name = ["/home/user1/first", "/home/user1/second"]
    observer = Observer()
    patterns = ["/home/user1/first/first.log","/home/user1/second/second.log")]
    for i in xrange(len(dir_name)):
        event_handler = EventHandler(patterns = patterns[i])
        observer.schedule(event_handler, dir_name[i], recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
```

In the above code, I tried to do multiple directory observing format and create an event handler for each of the files. It's not working for me. Is there anything that I am missing here?? What is the way to do this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

some wrong in here

```
EventHandler(patterns = patterns[i])
```

arg `patterns` is a type of list, so you can use like this

```
patterns = [["/home/user1/first/first.log"], ["/home/user1/second/second.log"]]
EventHandler(patterns = patterns[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using python3, LINUX OS

With a minor modification as suggested above and some additions from myside too this is working now

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class EventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
        def on_modified(self, event):
                super(EventHandler, self).on_modified(event)
                print(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        dir_name = ["/home/don/test1", "/home/don/test2"]
        observer = Observer()
        threads=[]
        patterns = [['*.log'],['*.ok']]
        for i in range(len(dir_name)):
                event_handler = EventHandler(patterns = patterns[i],ignore_directories=True,case_sensitive=False)
                observer.schedule(event_handler, dir_name[i], recursive=True)
                threads.append(observer)
        observer.start()

        try:
                while True:
                        time.sleep(0.1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

Answer (score -1):

Comparing with mine, you are lacking of `observer.join()` at the EOF. Try with that.

**EDIT**

Try this code below:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class EventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        super(EventHandler, self).on_modified(event)
        print event

if __name__ == "__main__":
    observer = Observer()
    patterns = ["/home/user1/first/first.log","/home/user1/second/second.log"]
    for pattern in patterns:
        event_handler = EventHandler(patterns=pattern)
        observer.schedule(event_handler, dir_name[i], recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: From what I know, blocks the thread from which is called the code, so the program runs indefenitely until it terminates (by a Ctrl-C in this case). More info [here](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.utils.BaseThread.join). Note that it stares as a black screen: make some changes so you can see if the program works (it will be outputed).

Comment: That's correct. But it's not at all printing anything even though the files are regularly modified at both the directories. I tried doing `join()` for all the observer schedulers. But it's not helping me.

Comment: Edited the post with some code to try. If keeps failing, search for the logs (usually syslog) to see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Though it does not use the watchdog library , this will the easy way just to check if the specific type of files are added or removed
if u want to check which files u can append them using any variable and store them in array

```
    import os
    import fnmatch
    import threading
    import time
    
    initial_count = 0
    flag = 0
    files = []
    
    path = ["/home/kirti/workspace/pythonproject6/img", "/home/kirti/workspace/pythonproject6/copy"]
    
    
    def taskcount(path, flag, initial_count):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(3)
            new_count = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), "*.jpg"))
    
            if new_count > initial_count:
    
                if flag != 0:
                    print("Added \nCount :", new_count, "=", path)
                else:
                    print(new_count)
            if new_count < initial_count:
                print("Removed \nCount :", new_count, "=", path)
    
            initial_count = new_count
            flag = 1
    
    
    for j in range(len(path)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=taskcount, args=(path[j], flag, initial_count))
    
        t.start()
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I have to say this, but this solution is terrible. Instead of using signals to monitor file changes, this solution has a loop with a timer to repeatedly check the path. This wastes CPU resources, and it introduces a delay with which changes are detected.

There's a reason why the question specifically asks about watchdog.